# Go to actual end of line when text is hidden under nowrap

Tags: vim, neovim

so my question is quite straight forward, I want to use `0` and `$` to go to the actual start/end of the line when I have the `nowrap` set. Basically `nowrap`'s version for `g0`and `g$` when `wrap` is set.

[image]

Comment: Is there something in your vimrc that is causing this behavior?  In my (vanilla) vim, `$` does go to the true end of line.

Comment: For me too, `0` and `$` work as you would like them to work. Furthermore, in my case, even if `l` moves only one char to the right, if it is at the right edge, causes the viewport to move by more than one char.

Comment: I guess I have to investigate that now, but thank you both for at least pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried:

```
g0 or g<Home>       When lines wrap ('wrap' on): To the first character of
            the screen line.  |exclusive| motion.  Differs from
            "0" when a line is wider than the screen.
            When lines don't wrap ('wrap' off): To the leftmost
            character of the current line that is on the screen.
            Differs from "0" when the first character of the line
            is not on the screen.

g$ or g<End>        When lines wrap ('wrap' on): To the last character of
            the screen line and [count - 1] screen lines downward
            |inclusive|.  Differs from "$" when a line is wider
            than the screen.
            When lines don't wrap ('wrap' off): To the rightmost
            character of the current line that is visible on the
            screen.  Differs from "$" when the last character of
            the line is not on the screen or when a count is used.
            Additionally, vertical movements keep the column,
            instead of going to the end of the line.
            When 'virtualedit' is enabled moves to the end of the
            screen line.
```

Comment: I had remapped `0` and `$` to `g0` and `g$` respectively as I was using the `wrap` on. So that's where the issue was. Thank you for the answer.